# Dates changed on the photos

Tags: samsung, date-and-time, exif

Photos were taken in 2011 on Samsung phone GT-B3310 (not a smartphone). This phone was switched off for over 2 years in 2013.

- On 24 January 2015 the phone was switched on and transferred the pictures via Bluetooth onto my Samsung Galaxy S3. The pictures showed dates from 24 to 28 January 2015. Some pictures had 24, some 26, 27 and 28. The `Exif` file also showed the dates from 24 to 28 January 2015. The original dates in 2011 were missing.
- Samsung South Korea said that if a device is switched off for long, and subsequently switched on and connected to a device (phone/computer) the pictures would take the switch off date.
- But the puzzle is, why do dates vary from 24 to 28 January 2015? Can anyone kindly give answer? This has created a *huge* issue/problem for me.

Comment: Are you sure that the metadata was modified? Normally on copy only the file's attributes are changed.

Comment: I didn't change anything. Due to the long switch off, the exif file was wiped off and it took the dates of the switched on date. The further puzzle is: the dates were different on batches of pictures from 24 to 28 January.

Comment: Could you add the reference to Samsung South Korea's statement? As explained on the answer, EXIF data is stored inside the image file itself; there's no separated EXIF file.

Answer (score 1):

`Exif` dates are stored in your images as strings, including the year. So the fact that the phone was off shouldn't be relevant.

However it's quite common that image transfer programs re-write metadata, unfortunately.

Try emailing yourself one of the images from the phone directly and testing with that on another computer (or find some other way to get a file off the phone for testing.)

Switching the phone off won't wipe any `Exif` data. That's stored inside the files.

Comment: This was an old phone. The pictures were taken in 2011 then the phone was off for around 2013. When switched on in 2015, the dates shown on the pictures were 24th January 2015. This phone may have been manufactured well before 2011.

Comment: The Samsung's report says:The phone has an internal DB file that manages images. If that becomes inactive for whatever reason, the dates will reset to the day it becomes active again. This only becomes an issue when the phone is off for a long period (years) of time and the customer has reported that the handset has been turned off for around 2 years.

Comment: The dates on all picture are not 24th Jan. 2015 but they are in batches: 4 batches have dates from 24, 26, 27 and 28 January 2015 on it.

Comment: Continued comments: I don't understand why the dates varied. One reason could be that these pictures were taken in batches on different days. Can you please advice why the dates are different on batches of pictures?

Comment: Don't forget that this was a old Non-Smart phone. Samsung's experts in South Korea have already stated that the dates could change after long-years of switch off.Ours was off for over 2 years. Only question we couldn't solve is why the dates on groups/batches of pictures are different. Can anyone help to solve this puzzle?.